# For which starting values the iteration convergences?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Given: $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a}{x})$ for $a\in \mathbb R_{>0}$

Question: For which starting values $x_0>0$ does the iteration $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$ converges?

My thoughts: Should I find an interval $I\subset \mathbb R$ such that $g$ has lipschitz constant smaller than $1$ on $I$?

Are there other ways to solve this?

Comment: Recognise that $g$ is the Newton iteration for $h\colon x \mapsto x^2 - a$. Use what you know about $h$ and Newton's method. Contractiveness is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: Observe $$\left(\frac{x_{k+1}-\sqrt{a}}{x_{k+1}+\sqrt{a}}\right)=\left(\frac{x_{k}-\sqrt{a}}{x_{k}+\sqrt{a}}\right)^2$$

Comment: prove that $g(x)$ is positive for all $x_0>0$ and then use $AM-GM$

Comment: @DanielFischer I only know theorems which are like: "...then $x_{k+1}$ converges in a sufficient small neighborhood of the zero $x*$. So how can I agar here?

Comment: In a Newton iteration, how is $x_{k+1}$ related to $x_k$? [A description in words, so that the idea behind it becomes apparent, not a formula, is what I'm after.]

Comment: $x_{k+1}$ is the intersection between the tangent of the point $(x_k,f(x_k))$ (on the graph) and the x-axis. $(f'(x_k)$ must be unequal zero)

Comment: Ah, you didn't ping me, so I only now saw it. Yes, that's exactly what I was after. Now, if $f$ is convex and increasing, what follows geometrically for the Newton iteration?